# How to access an element of a list using a variable in python

Tags: python, list

Given that I have a target location for a multi-dimensional list. I.e. an index stored in a variable.

```
list = [[1,2,3,4,5],
        [10,20,30,40,50],
        [5,4,3,2,1],
        [50,40,30,20,10]]
target = [3][4]
```

How do I access list[target]?

```
  >>> list[target]
    10
```

Comment: `list[3][4][1]`?

Comment: What is `list[target]` supposed to mean?

Comment: What is `target = [3][4][1]` supposed to mean?

Comment: I think he wants to store the indexes into one variable and pass that variable in as "keys" to access the value

Comment: I was just wondering how to access elements of list using variables

Comment: Give an example of `list`, and the value you expect from `list[target]`

Comment: What is target exactly? This isn't a valid data structure. Is it a 1D list with 3 elements? Is it a list of lists?

Comment: I thought the question makes perfect sense, he wants to be able to access `list[3][4][1]` using a variable instead of the `[3][4][1]`

Answer (score 5):

If `target` is given as a list of indices like `[3, 4, 1]`, you can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce # not required in py2

result = reduce(list.__getitem__, target, my_list)
```

Note that this won't work if you've used `list` as a name for your variable. Never use the names of builtins for your variables. Name it `my_list` or something more descriptive.

Comment: It was really simple, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly because list[variable] will become an entry of the list; the variable must be an index.

So what you need is some way to get list[variable][variable][variable]

This can't be done with a simple variable sadly, even though it would be really cool.

The best way to do it would be to make a recursive function to do it, which takes your list `target=[3,4,1]` and returns the value, as so.

```
def target_value(my_list, place):
    if len(place) == 1:
        return my_list[place[0]]
    return target_value(my_list[place[0]],place[1:])
```

Then you would call it as a normal function, giving your list and target (`target = [3,4,1]`) as parameters.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Rawing's version is more simple if you want to import outside functions, or this recursive one will work if you want it to be part of your program.